# Dynamic 301 Redirect

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

We made a mistake in the scope of our dynamic pages on a new site, and have some incorrect pages already spidered in Google.

I need to redirect the following format:
http://www.domain.com/dir/dir/?q=120

To this format:
http://www.domain.com/dir/dir/?p=120

Only difference is the 'q' needs to be a 'p'.

RewriteEngine is on, as I've already consolidated traffic from domain.com to www.domain.com

This is what I have in my root .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^centerline.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301] 
RewriteRule ^(/leadership/detail/)\?q=([0-9]+)$    $1?p=$2 [R=301, L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?p=%1 [L,R=301]
```

You'll need the `RewriteCond` as apache doesn't allow matching against the querystring in a `RewriteRule`

**EDIT**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/leadership/detail/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=([0-9]+)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?p=%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hmm, still not working. This syntax is correct:
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^(/leadership/detail/)$ /$1?p=%1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the specific request-uri you're looking for.