# Dynamic 301 Redirect Fighting with Wordpress

Tags: regex, apache, wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

This is a followup to another question I asked earlier ([Earlier redirect question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721544/dynamic-301-redirect)). My root .htaccess has several rules in this format:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/leadership/detail/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=([0-9]+)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?p=%1 [L,R=301]
```

But when I tried to add this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/detail/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=([0-9]+)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?p=%1 [L,R=301]
```

It didn't work. /blog/ is a Wordpress install and I'm thinking in it's conflicting with the .htaccess file that's in /blog/ that has the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Where can I insert (or edit) code snippet #2 in the /blog/.htaccess file to make it work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your combined .htaccess like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/detail/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1?p=%1 [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^p= [NC]
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: thanks. Got it working with one small change: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/detail/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=([0-9]+)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1?p=%1 [L,R=301]`

I needed it to redirect to /blog/detail instead of /detail/

Comment: Glad that it is working fine for you. I actually copied that line from your question above which didn't have `/blog/` in the target URL.

Comment: Yeah, my fault. I have other redirects in the root .htaccess file that I copied that from. Appreciate the help.